# Giving advice: Do you think it wouldn't be a good idea to...?

Tags: will-would

If I want to advise you, I can say, e.g.:

- You should see a doctor
- You ought to get to the doctor
- Do you think it would**n't** be a good idea to see a doctor?

https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/initial/functions/form_function.html#2

Is the third example grammatically correct?

Comment: I would find it much more natural to say _Don't you think it would be a good idea to see a doctor?_

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are politely implying that you think that person should see a doctor, and seeking their agreement, the correct question is "Don't you think it would be a good idea to see a doctor?" For example "Don't you think you should go to bed early on weekdays? (You are suggesting they should go to bed).
2. On the other hand, if you are just asking their opinion, the correct answer is "Do you think it wouldn't be a good idea to see a doctor?" For example "So, do you think Mary shouldn't stay up late on weekdays?" (You are not recommending a course of action, but they have a preconceived negative opinion).

Answer (score 1):

The third example is not grammatically wrong (if a little clunky), but doesn't mean what you want it to. It is a straight question.

"Do you think it would be a good idea to see a doctor?" could be a suggestion (in context), but might be considered slightly passive-aggressive.